# Transition speed and order in CSS

Tags: html, css

the community

I try to make a kind of overlay menu with HTML and CSS.

Here's my idea: when my mouse hovers the pink rectangle an animation reveals the blue box then another animation reveals the red box.
It's like a 'double' dropdown menu.

My HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Visualization</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="stats-dropdown">
      <div id="stats-title"><span>Rendering statistics</span></div>
      <div id="stats">
        <div>Number of Instances : 50</div>
        <div>Number of Surfaces : 1200</div>
        <div>Number of Patches : 5000</div>
        <div>Number of Elements : 10000</div>
        <div>Number of Vertices : 30000</div>
        <div>Running time : 50 ms</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#stats-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;

  font-size: larger;
  font-family: 'Courier', Arial, monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;

  background-color: palevioletred;
  height: 40px;
  width: 20px;
}

#stats-title {
  background-color: teal;

  width: 350px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;

  display: flex;

  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto
}

#stats-title > span {
  margin: auto;
}

#stats {
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 20px;

  background-color: tomato;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
}

#stats-dropdown #stats {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

#stats-dropdown #stats-title {
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#stats-dropdown:hover #stats {
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
}

#stats-dropdown:hover #stats-title {
  height: 40px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

MY problems are that during the "closing" animation the red box disappears without animation and sometimes I noticed that the red box can also appears before the blue one in spite of the transition delay.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frbtnmhd/) if you want to give it a try.

Can you help me to figure out my issues?

I run this on Firefox (don't know if this matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Please check this I have tried to accomplished according to your query. I have added few lines please check. `position: absolute; top: 100%;` in `#stats`

```css
#stats-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: larger;
  font-family: 'Courier', Arial, monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  background-color: palevioletred;
  height: 40px;
  width: 20px;
}

#stats-title {
  background-color: teal;
  width: 350px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

#stats-title>span {
  margin: auto;
}

#stats-dropdown #stats-title {
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#stats-dropdown:hover #stats-title {
  height: 40px;
  width: 350px;
}

#stats {
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: tomato;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  ;
}

#stats-dropdown:hover #stats {
  height: 250px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div id="stats-dropdown">
  <div id="stats-title"><span>Rendering statistics</span></div>
  <div id="stats">
    <div>Number of Instances : 50</div>
    <div>Number of Surfaces : 1200</div>
    <div>Number of Patches : 5000</div>
    <div>Number of Elements : 10000</div>
    <div>Number of Vertices : 30000</div>
    <div>Running time : 50 ms</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Still able to see the immediate disappearance of the red box, but I solved the problem of the red box appearing before the title box:

```
#stats {
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 20px;

  background-color: tomato;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The main difference was the `transition-delay: 0.5s;` which delays the transition `0.5s`, which is the amount of time it takes the title to appear. But, regarding the immediate disappearance of the red box, I'm still working... Sorry for a half reply, I'll try to work on it and add on as soon as I find an answer. I hope this much works for the delay.